# SharePoint 2010 - Hide specific tag in tag cloud web part

Tags: web-part, tagcloud

I would like to hide a specific tag in the tag cloud web part. I do not won't to delete the tag, only hide it in the tag cloud. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easiest (not the best) approach is to hide it using CSS. Each tag has its own GUID. You can get the term GUID using firebug/IE developer tool and look for a parent div class which wraps/contains the tags.

Ex. If a tag has GUID ("15d30155-784c-4193-8289-2636b39e399c") and the div that contains the tags has a class named "ms-TagCloud", you could do something like:

```
div.ms-TagCloud a[href$="15d30155-784c-4193-8289-2636b39e399c"] {
    display: none;
}
```